# How to register a new MIB module?

Tags: snmp, mib

For those who have tried using the net-snmp library, how do you add a new mib module?
What I so far did was generate a template newmodule.c and newmodule.h files using the mib2c command. Now, I don't know where to place the init_newmodule() function to register the new mib during start up of net-snmp application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your snmpd.conf, add:

```
dlmod myNewModule /path/to/libnewmodule.so
```

This will load libnewmodule.so and call init_myNewModule().